# on key pressed javafx scene builder

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, keyevent

```
@FXML
void afficher(KeyEvent event) {
   
    if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
    }
```

I want to make a simple key pessed method, but Netbeans underlines the `getCode()` in red whatever I do.

I got:

```
cannot find symbol symbol: method getCode() location: variable event of type KeyEvent
Flip operands of the binary operator
```

Comment: what's the message you get?

Comment: I get like : flip operands with '=='

Comment: and : Invert If

Comment: also i got :    cannot find symbol    symbol: method getCode()     location: variable event of type KeyEvent      Flip operands of the binary operator

Comment: [mcve] please..

Answer (score 4):

Most probably you have imported the `KeyEvent` from the `java.awt.event.KeyEvent` package, you should import it from `javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent`